# Entourage window resizing issue

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

Could someone tell me how to retain the email window to the full page size eachtime I open entourage.?

When I open the new email window it opens in a small window, in then have to drag the window to use it comfortably.

I close down reataining these sizes and when I open the entourage later it always goes back to the small window!

It is driving me crazy?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely that your Entourage preferences file is corrupted in some fashion. Try this:

1. Close Entourage.
2. Navigate to `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Entourage.plist`.
3. Move the file to the Desktop.
4. Open Entourage, resize the window to your preferred size. Entourage will automatically make a new preferences file.
5. Close and open Entourage again to test that the change sticks.

If all is well, you can trash the original `com.microsoft.Entourage.plist` file from your Desktop.